# Calculus Question about Rolle’s Theorem pertaining to velocity and acceleration

Tags: calculus

At 9:13 A.M., a sports car is traveling 35 miles per hour. Two minutes later, the car is traveling 85 miles per hour. Prove that at some time during this two-minute interval, the car’s acceleration is exactly 1500 miles per hour squared.

Answer (score 1):

I assume the acceleration is constant. 
First observe that 2 minutes is equivalent to $2/60=1/30$ hours. 
The equation that describe velocity as a function of time is $$v=v(t)=at+v_0,$$ where $a$ is the acceleration and $v_0$ is the initial velocity. Since $t\mapsto v(t)$ is linear then is continuous in $[0,1/30]$ and derivable in $(0,1/30)$. Using the Mean Value theorem we see that there exists $c\in (0,1/30)$ such that $$v’(t)= \frac{v(1/30)-v(0)}{1/30-0}=\frac{85-35}{1/30}=50\cdot 30=1500.$$ Since $v’(t):=a(t)$ we have that at $t=c$ the acceleration of the car is $1500$ miles per hour squared.

Comment: That seems like a pretty strong assumption to make.  What about OP's mention of Rolle's Theorem (or maybe, the Mean Value Theorem)?

Comment: @Matthew Leingang I’m sorry but I don’t understand the question.

Answer (score 1):

The [Mean Value Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem) states that if $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and differentiable on $(a,b)$, then there exists a point $c$ in $(a,b)$ such that 
$$
    \frac{f(b) - f(a)}{b-a} = f'(c)
$$
If you think of $f$ as varying over time, the left-hand side is the average rate of change of $f$ over the interval $[a,b]$, and the right-hand side is the instantaneous rate of change at $c$.

You mentioned Rolle's Theorem in your title; the MVT is equivalent to it.

If $f$ is velocity, what is $f'$?